# How to move cursor diagonally in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to write functions that move cursor diagonally, for example:

```
(defun leftUp ()
    (backward-char)
    (previous-line))
```

but it works only once. On next calls cursor just moves straight up.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previous-line` always tries to place the cursor on the same column as the cursor movement originally started in. See the variable `goal-column` for more information.

Comment: I added `(setq temporary-goal-column nil)` to the beginning and now it works, thanks.